# Save command output as environment variables

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

If the command `my_command` has this output:

```
VAR1=some_value
VAR2=other_value
```

**is it possible to call `my_command` from a shell script so that both `VAR1` and `VAR2` are saved as environment variables?**

I tried the following ways, and none of them works:

```
#!/bin/bash
source my_command
export `my_command`
```

However if I manually enter

```
export `my_command`
```

in a terminal console, then both variables are saved.

Comment: @ilkkachu If `export ...` works in a shell and not in a script, is it not the same as that one?

Comment: @ilkkachu it is if the script contains ``export `mycommand` `` like in the question.

Comment: @muru, well, right, that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set variables of the parent shell in a shell script you call from it. Either

- set the variables as usual in the script but source it: `. my_command`
- have the script print the variables to be set to `stdout` and `eval`uate the result

  ```
  $ cat foo.sh 
  #!/bin/sh
  echo FOO=foo
  echo BAR=bar
  $ ./foo.sh 
  FOO=foo
  BAR=bar
  $ eval $(./foo.sh)
  $ echo $FOO
  foo
  $ echo $BAR
  bar
  ```

Comment: Took me an hour to find this answer. This is what you want to do instead of piping to bash or trying other ways of executing stdout. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you have `my_command` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'VAR1=some_value'
echo 'VAR2=other_value'
```

running it obviously prints

```
VAR1=some_value
VAR2=other_value
```

Now, `source my_command` will *run* the script, in the current shell, which will just produce the assignments as output. You would use `source` if `my_command` didn't print the assignments, but executed then directly.

`export $(my_command)` will take the output of the script, and pass it to export, which will put the variables in the current shell environment, *but* it only works as long as the variables in question don't contain whitespace or glob characters, since the command substitution is unquoted. Putting `"$(my_command)"` in quotes doesn't really help, because then `export` sees `VAR1=some_value\nVAR2=other_value` as one argument, and only `VAR1` is set.

Note that having running `export $(my_command)` or setting variables in any other way within another script will not set those variables in the parent shell. If you want the assignments in your interactive shell, you must run them there, but you could wrap the assigments in a function or `source` a script that makes the assignments.

---

One, obvious solution would be to do what `ssh-agent` does, and have the script output `export` commands for the variables it sets. Then it would be enough to run `eval "$(my_command)"`.

If we don't want to do that, we can use `set -a` before the script to have the shell automatically export any variables that are set.

So,

```
$ set -a
$ eval "$(my_command)"
```

In Bash, we can use `declare -p` to check that the variables are exported (`-x`):

```
$ declare -p VAR1 VAR2
declare -x VAR1="some_value"
declare -x VAR2="other_value"
```

Using `eval` here will allow the script to output quoted strings like `VAR1="foo bar"`, and they will be handled correctly. `eval` will also run anything else the script `my_command` outputs, not just assignments, but if you didn't trust `my_command`, you shouldn't run it at all.